# How do I find out which boot loader I have?

Tags: bootloader, embedded-system

I know Grub is the one installed by default when installing Ubuntu but I am faced with an embedded system running 9.10 Desktop Edition. Following are the contents of lsb-release file

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-desktop:/boot$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=9.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=karmic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 9.10"
```

but this system does not have Grub bootloader and I want to find out which one its using. So any ideas?

Comment: http://wiki.debian.org/BootLoader lists all the boot loaders available in Debian, if you'd like to check each one. What arch is the system? Just leaving a comment as this isn't a proper answer...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The boot info script will detect all kinds of useful information about your boot configuration:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/

Answer (score 17):

If you have the `/etc/lilo.conf` file then you are using LILO (LInux LOader)
This means that if you type `lilo` for example you should see the command dialog for the lilo booter.

If you have the `/boot/grub/` directory then you are using GRUB (Grand Unified Boot Loader)
This means that you should be able to use all the grub file like grub-install,grub-reboot...

Ubuntu 9.10 was the first version to use GRUB2 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DualBoot/Grub

**UPDATE:**

Here is a script to check inside the first sector of the hard drive for what boot manager it is using:

Assuming your hard drive is at SDA then:

`sudo dd if=/dev/sda bs=512 count=1 2>/dev/null | strings | grep -Eoi 'grub|lilo|acronis|reboot'`

will tell you which bootloader you are using.

You can imagine the rest...
The list of boot loaders is here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_boot_loaders  and http://wiki.debian.org/BootLoader (For Debian based distros)
Also if you want to SEE the real binary output then add -a to the grep part. For example:

`sudo dd if=/dev/sda bs=512 count=1 2>&1 | grep -a GRUB` which will show you the data in that first block.

Now with this new information you HAVE to find the boot manager you are using.

Comment: nops, dont have any of these.

Comment: Updated with a small command line for you.

Comment: Also try cycling through `sda1`, `sda2` etc in case you have a rescue partition set up.

Comment: How do I find out if I am on VPS and this approch does not work? (device is /dev/simfs and command produces no output)

Comment: @thegeko that is a very big question because it depends on your provider, the software they are using, the service they are offering (IaaS, PaaS, MaaS, Cloud, Dedicated, Virtual, etc..)

Comment: What if I have /boot/grub but also /boot/efi? What is efi anyway? And if efi is also a bootloader, how can I tell which of the two is actually used?

Answer (score 4):

For GRUB the command to check what version you have is:

```
grub-install -V
```

or

```
grub-install --version
```

More to find here:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2

Comment: the grub package installs tools to help install grub, but using the tools doesn't definitely tell you which bootloader is installed on the boot disk. One could, for example, boot from grub, then install lilo _packages_ and remove grub _packages_.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `dd` command to read the boot sector, then use `grep` to know your bootloader:

```
dd if=/dev/hda bs=512 count=1 2>&1 | grep GRUB
dd if=/dev/hda bs=512 count=1 2>&1 | grep LILO
```

Comment: Nope, does not work at all. This returns a blob of binary data with no strings in them to grep through. Might only work for a very specific kind of hardware and BIOS combination.

Answer (score 0):

You are safer checking by inquiring the version from the tools itself (than using low-level dd or other artifacts).

For example, testing for lilo:

```
root# lilo -V
bash: lilo: command not found

root# grub-install --version
grub-install (GRUB) 2.02~beta2-22
```

Of course, this will not work if you have both installed. If that is the case, to avoid confusion, uninstall the ones you don't need.

Comment: bootloader packages install tools to help install the bootloader, but using those tools doesn't definitively tell you which bootloader is installed on the boot disk. You could, for example, boot from grub, then install lilo _packages_ and remove grub _packages_.

Comment: I suppose "boot from grub" doesn't answer the question either, as this is what the OP asked in the first place. Anyway, a bit tricky, but I prefer using easier commands to avoid destructive mistakes when/if possible. If not, well, this answer is not suitable for you, then I recommend that you ry to read the other suggestions in other answers.

Comment: Today I found myself googling this same problem again, and ended up reading this answer. To my surprise I received a message "you can't downvote your own answer"! Haha! The current machine I'm probing has both `lilo` and `grub` installed. Also, the `dd` command didn't work.