# How to know the version of GRUB

Tags: command-line, grub2

How do I find the version of GRUB that is running in a particular version of Ubuntu? I want a terminal command that tells me.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

For me the above answer given by @Daniel does not work. I have *Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (this also works with Ubuntu 17.10)* and to check the version of Grub (Grub2) I need to type:

```
grub-install --version
```

[image: check grub2 version]

Comment: Correct they seemed to have changed it with some newer version. Just like in `apt` where `apt-get update -f` won't work anymore and you'll have to use the explicit `apt-get update --fix-missing`

Comment: works with 16.04 LTS as well :)

Comment: sudo grub-install --version for debian.

Comment: Works with 20.04 LTS as well.

Comment: But is this **_Grub_** version 2.02 or **_Grub2_** version 2.02?

Comment: I entered this from the grub-repair command line and it did not recognize the command grub-install. How do we ask grub what version it is running?

Comment: @alife --> https://askubuntu.com/a/107487/1735819

Answer (score 20):

On clean ubuntu installs the grub package itself doesn't seem to be installed. Thus typing 'grub -anyoption' results in an error that says grub is not installed.
However you can type for example

```
grub-install -v
```

And it will give you the correct version of grub currently installed

[image]


The version of the Grub is `1.99-21ubuntu3`

**EDIT:** As others have pointed out the commandline flags have been changed in newer versions. So now instead of typing `grub-install -v` you'd have to use a capital 'V' or the explicit `--version`

Comment: I find it more friendly this way. Also grub-probe -V works.

Comment: basicly everything in your /usr/bin folder that starts with 'grub' does the job

Comment: Uppercase `-V`, not lowercase.

Comment: Ahh thanks for the hint! They must have changed it with a newer version..I'll edit it in the post

Answer (score 7):

This will roughly do the job:

```
dpkg -l | grep grub | grep ii
```

You should note that just to confuse things that the version 1.9x is known as Grub2. I think they number it in a similar way that people would call the 1600-1699, the 17th century.

Comment: I find it weird that there is no command for it. like a grub command that grub -v and done. Thanks again Oli you rock ^^.

Comment: I think that v1.9 is supposed to be "pre-Grub2" - i.e., an _almost_ ready version. Yet, you'd think that _2.0.x RC#_ would have been better naming for them...

Comment: The thing is--the grub you may be using to boot may not be installed from the Ubuntu system you are currently running. Therefore I prefer the other answer.

Comment: "GRUB 2 is the default boot loader and manager for Ubuntu since version 9.10 (Karmic Koala)." .... "In this guide, GRUB 2 is version 1.98 or later. GRUB legacy (version 0.97) will be referred to as GRUB. " from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2

Answer (score 5):

It can be also found out with either of these:

```
grub-probe --version 
grub-probe -V
```

Answer (score 3):

to find out what bootloader you're using, you have to look at the bootloader!

try `dd if=/dev/sda bs=512 count=1 2> /dev/null | grep -q GRUB && echo "GRUB found"`

---

All querying of installed packages, as described in the other answers, miss an important point: to probe your bootloader, look at the bootloader!

In other words, you can install whatever *packages* you like in whatever OS or distro you like, but none of this has anything to do with the bootloader you'll use when you reboot.

specifically,
for MBR/msdos partitioned disks: **probe the MBR** (i.e. look at the bootloader to see what bootloader you're using)

This duplicate has some good answers: [How do I find out which boot loader I have?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24459/how-do-i-find-out-which-boot-loader-i-have)

I like this more complete answer, found in a newer question:
question: https://superuser.com/questions/466086/how-can-i-discover-which-bootloader-is-installed-where
answer: https://superuser.com/a/466248

Answer (score 2):

The package name is grub-pc, so you can do this:

```
dpkg -l grub-pc
```

which will show you something like this:

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                     Version                   Architecture              Description
+++-========================================-=========================-=========================-=====================================================================================
ii  grub-pc                                  2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.7     amd64                     GRand Unified Bootloader, version 2 (PC/BIOS version)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll throw my hat into the ring as well.  You can also do it with `apt-cache policy grub-pc`

```
:~$ apt-cache policy grub-pc
grub-pc:
  Installed: 2.02-2ubuntu8.7
  Candidate: 2.02-2ubuntu8.7
  Version table:
 *** 2.02-2ubuntu8.7 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.02-2ubuntu8 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```