# After installation Ubuntu/Mint loops continuously to grub

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, mint

My Lenovo P50 can't boot Linux.

I have Windows 10 installed on my SSD (with BitLocker *-- I tried deactivating that before Linux installation, without any success*). I used its Disk Manager to split the main SSD in two, and the second HDD also in 2.
Then I booted on my USB stick and installed my Linux distribution (tried several versions of `Ubuntu` up to `18.10` & `Mint` up to `19.1`) choosing SSD for `/`, HDD for `/home` and `/dev/sda` (SSD) for grub. The installation process works OK. Live Linux works perfectly fine, but when I'm rebooting the laptop hangs on a grub prompt. The only option I found so far is `exit` which then brings me to a BIOS boot menu where I can select between Windows Boot Manager, Linux Xxx and any other bootable device (my USB stick, etc.).

If I choose `Linux Xxx`, it turns to a black screen and goes back to that grub prompt. If I choose `Windows...` it boots fine.

Where could the problem be? What kind of grub command or option could I try? Where should I look for eventual logs? How can I "debug" or provide you with more details so we can fix the problem?

FYI, this is not a duplicate of "[How to get info on my current GRUB / boot configuration?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/353254/how-to-get-info-on-my-current-grub-boot-configuration)". I am booting with EFI, I have an ESP (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#Creating_an_EFI_System_Partition), I'm using GPT.

[image: Disk partitioning with ESP, Principal partition for C drive & principal partition for <code>/</code>]

grub2 is launched but in "prompt" mode. And none of the options I tried except "exit" are offering any solution. Lately, I tried to run boot, but it complains that I must first load the kernel. I have no idea about how to do this.

I assume there is also something to do with `bcdedit`, but I'm not very familiar with it and I'm afraid I could break the entire system messing with it.

[image: bcdedit content]

Comment: Hi @mikewhatever Thanks for your tips, but unfortunately it does not concern my problem. I have edited my question accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, this question is NOT a duplicate. I explained WHY in the core. Please remove that mark. @mikewhatever